# Can't debug pywin32 service

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to debug my service with `PythonService.exe` and I get a strange error:

```
PS C:\Users\rs_al\Dev\PyXLSQL> py serviceapp.py install
Installing service pyxlsql
Changing service configuration
Service updated
PS C:\Users\rs_al\Dev\PyXLSQL> py serviceapp.py debug
Debugging service pyxlsql - press Ctrl+C to stop.
Error 0xC0000004 - Python could not import the service's module

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'w32service'

(null): (null)
```

Project structure

```
serviceapp.py
    w32service\
               __init__.py
               service.py
```

And if I move whole code from `service.py` into `serviceapp.py` I can debug it without issues.

EDIT:

```
gui.py
gui\
    __init__.py
    menu.py
    pageone.py
    pagetwo.py
    pagethree.py
```

And it perfectly works as `*.py` or `.*exe`

Comment: Are *serviceapp.py* and *w32service* located in the same dir? It's not clear from the tree.

Comment: In same project dir

Comment: And how does the import look like in *serviceapp.py*?

Comment: ‘from w32service.service import WinService‘.

Comment: You might be missing an `__init__.py` in the folder holding `serviceapp.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Python* interpreter doesn't know where to look for your *w32service* module (package). One way would be to add its path to [[Python 3.Docs]: Modules - The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) (**before** importing it):

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from w32service.service import WinService

# ...
```

To make things clearer, use `print(sys.path)` before importing anything (well, except *sys*) to see where is the *Python* searching for modules.

Comment: Could you explain why I can then import in `gui.py` in the same dir as `serviceapp.py` from package `gui`? `gui` is on the same level as `w32service`. I still don't undestand Python imports.

Comment: Unfortunately without additional details I can't. whith the code above you'll be able to import **any** package from *serviceapp*'s dir.

Comment: I've edited my question. I accept your solution, but if you could explain me why other imports works without issue, I would be appreciate.

Comment: I assume that you have something similar in *service.py*. As a note you have a *gui.py* and a *gui* dir with *\_\_init\_\_.py*,  so you have 2 entities with the same name which could yield unexpected results. Anyway if you could post a [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (short files ~1 line of code), I'd be happy to investigate.